# Node.js Create new Routes from TCP Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have the following code, which is meant to capture JSON data through TCP, and then create a new route based on whatever is in the JSON file. So If one of my JSON files has:

```
{"pagename": "singsong"}
```

Then I want my route to be `mywebsite:8000/singsong` and contain all data from whatever has the `singsong` pagename.

The problem I am facing is that my TCP data gets sent to all routes. So my route `mywebsite:8000/singsong` will contain JSON data that has `{"pagename": "hazel"}`, when I am trying to create new routes for each data.

My code, as is:

```
server.on("connection", function(socket){
    chunk = "";
socket.on('data', function(data){
    chunk += data.toString(); // Add string on the end of the variable 'chunk'
    d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the delimiter

    // While loop to keep going until no delimiter can be found
    while (d_index > -1) {         
        try {
            string = chunk.substring(0,d_index); // Create string up until the delimiter
            json = JSON.parse(string); // Parse the current string
            app.set('fee', data);
            app.set('dee', json);
            console.log(json.pagename); // Function that does something with the current chunk of valid json.    
                app.get("/"+json.pagename, function(req, res){
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(req.app.get('dee')));
                    res.end();
                });
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
        chunk = chunk.substring(d_index+1); // Cuts off the processed chunk
        d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the new delimiter
    }      
});
        socket.on("close", function(){
            console.log("connection closed");
        });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "TCP data gets sent to all routes"?  From the code you show, it looks like the TCP data gets sent to your socket.  FYI, this is a very odd way to configure a server.  Can you explain a bit about why you're doing it this way (what you're really trying to accomplish) because I'm getting there's a different (perhaps better) way to approach whatever actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes. The socket generates a route. `app.get("/"+json.pagename)`. So if I send two packets, then the latest will populate both of the routes that have been generated.

Comment: And, the problem is what?

Comment: that I want the data to be sent to the appropriate route. JSON with `{"pagename:" "singsong", "data": "A"}` should go to `mywebsite:8000/singsong` and JSON with `{"pagename:" "hazel", "data": "B"}` should go to `mywebsite:8000/hazel`

Comment: Why are you defining routes this way?  This is extremely odd.  Usually, you'd have one predetermined master route that gets all the requests for this type of route and then looks at what's in the rest of the path and compares to a table of data you've stored.  It's very unusual to create routes after the fact while the server is running.

Comment: So, if you want to run this code multiple times and have separate data to send them, then stop storing stuff every single piece of data in the same `app.set('fee', ...)` and `app.set('dee', ...)`.  You can use closure variables.  I'm still not thinking this is the best way to do things if we understood WHY you're doing this?

Comment: wow. closures worked. thanks for that. as to why im doing things this way, it's because i have a server that needs to keep running, since multiple items are sending data via TCP to it. I cannot plan for all these items, and so I don't have a database for them. Instead, I have a new route made for each as the data is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of capturing the json for each specific request in a closure variable (defined with `let`) instead of using the `app.set()` that makes every single request conflict as they try to use the same storage location:

```
server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    let chunk = "";
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        chunk += data.toString(); // Add string on the end of the variable 'chunk'
        let d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the delimiter

        // While loop to keep going until no delimiter can be found
        while (d_index > -1) {
            try {
                let string = chunk.substring(0, d_index); // Create string up until the delimiter

                // define local variables that can be used in a closure
                let json = JSON.parse(string); // Parse the current string
                let localData = data;
                console.log(json.pagename); // Function that does something with the current chunk of valid json.    
                app.get("/" + json.pagename, function(req, res) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                    });
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(json));
                    res.end();
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            chunk = chunk.substring(d_index + 1); // Cuts off the processed chunk
            d_index = chunk.indexOf(';'); // Find the new delimiter
        }
    });
    socket.on("close", function() {
        console.log("connection closed");
    });
});
```

Also, note that I define ALL your variables with `let` so they are properly scoped inside the function and not accidental globals which is likely to create hard-to-find bugs.